# How would you turn number to date in excel?

Tags: excel, date

How to convert this string(number): 201410010955

to date time:

01-10-2014 09:55

in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,7,2))+TIME(MID(A1,9,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

and format the cells as Custom:

**dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm**

Answer (score 0):

if your current string is in this format YYYYMMDDHHSS then:

```
=DATE(MID(C4,1,4),MID(C4,5,2),MID(C4,7,2))+TIME(MID(C4,9,2),MID(C4,11,2),0)
```

It will return a number, set the format to the date you need it