# Convert Number Format of a Column into Date "dd.mm.yyyy"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the number format of the columns G, H and I to short-date format (dd.mm.yyyy).

```
sheet.Range("G1").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
sheet.Range("H1").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
sheet.Range("I1").End(xlDown).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```

The cells G84 (last cell filled of this column), H2, I2 (first cells filled of these columns) are now in a proper format, the rest is still just a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you turn number to date in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367024/how-would-you-turn-number-to-date-in-excel)

Comment: @Rawrplus That answer does not really help me tbh, I "knew" (or actually it turns out that I did not really knew) how to format, my question was why it would not work with the code I provided, since it did format some of the cells properly, so I would say that this is not really a duplicate of the other question

Comment: Well the `=DATE()` formula enforces the Date Format unless you have a different (custom) format selected. So technically it does answer your question, but that is fine. After all, it says a *Possible duplicate*, emphasis on the possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "macro recorder":

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("G:I").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

You would get this:

[image]

If you want to get the cells from the first cell in a column to the first cell before an empty space then this would be ok:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Sheet1
        .Range(.Range("E1"), .Range("E1").End(xlDown)) = .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

To get the range from `E1` to the last used cell in column E:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Sheet1
        MsgBox .Range(.Range("E1"), .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Address
        .Range(.Range("E1"), .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided `Sheet` is the `Sheet Code Name`, try it like this...

```
Sheet.Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
Sheet.Range("H1", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
Sheet.Range("I1", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
Sheet.Columns("G:I").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
```